# Connecting Bluetooth mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I have a problem with my mouse I just bougth two days ago. It's a Logitech MX anywhere 2. I could connect it once and was able to pair it, but now I can not connect it anymore. Does any of you have a solution for that?

```
[bluetooth]# info FE:DE:88:B7:83:89
Device FE:DE:88:B7:83:89
Name: MX Anywhere 2
Alias: MX Anywhere 2
Appearance: 0x03c2
Icon: input-mouse
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: no
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Vendor specific           (00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d)
Modalias: usb:v046DpB013d0007
RSSI: -94
[bluetooth]# connect FE:DE:88:B7:83:89
Attempting to connect to FE:DE:88:B7:83:89
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's been blocked by `rfkill`. Try using this command to unblock it.

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

If it is successful, then have a look at `/etc/default/tlp` file. Most probably, TLP is blocking bluetooth. There should be a line like this

```
DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="wifi bluetooth"
```

Edit the file and remove `bluetooth` from there. Then bluetooth will be available from startup.

Also make sure, you have enabled all hardware switches.

Comment: Thanks this worked, the mouse is now connected. But the problem is that it lags terribly. I guess Ubuntu may not be made for my mouse..

Comment: Objection: neither is TLP installed by default (only for Ubuntu MATE flavor) nor is DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP enabled in TLP's default config. Therefore i doubt above answer is a sustained solution

Answer (score 0):

**Only** when you have [TLP](http://linrunner.de/tlp) installed:

Try to exclude (blacklist) your internal USB bluetooth adaptor from powersave --> see [TLP FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#input).