# Some bluetooth devices not found

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth, firmware

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, so far I've only had this problem. 
Bluetooth is working; in fact, my BT headphones are connected and working properly.

My BT mouse is not found, I just get "searching for devices" all the time. I know it's compatible with Ubuntu because I tried it at work and no problem.

Weird, right?

I think it has something to do with the firmware, but this is a tad beyond my capabilities. I would appreciate any guidance.

I tried many of the suggestions that pop up in google :(, I updated everything.

Help to a fellow human.

By looking in `/var/log/syslog` I got the following:

```
Feb 20 19:38:06 Uthred kernel: [    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
Feb 20 19:38:06 Uthred kernel: [    0.143961] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
Feb 20 19:38:06 Uthred kernel: [    1.882708] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin failed with error -2
Feb 20 19:38:06 Uthred kernel: [    1.882709] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware], disabling runtime power management.
Feb 20 19:38:06 Uthred kernel: [    8.356777] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
Feb 20 19:38:07 Uthred NetworkManager[844]: <info>  [1519173487.1039] manager[0xa11200]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred kernel: [    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred kernel: [    0.137387] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred kernel: [    1.872620] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin failed with error -2
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred kernel: [    1.872622] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware], disabling runtime power management.
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred kernel: [    8.312739] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
Feb 20 19:50:30 Uthred NetworkManager[809]: <info>  [1519174230.4601] manager[0x237c200]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred kernel: [    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred kernel: [    0.140260] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred kernel: [    1.876657] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin failed with error -2
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred kernel: [    1.876658] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware], disabling runtime power management.
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred kernel: [    8.316400] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
Feb 20 20:23:52 Uthred NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1519176232.4860] manager[0xd7b200]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 20 22:41:57 Uthred NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1519184517.8840] manager: kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware' changed
Feb 20 22:42:01 Uthred NetworkManager[885]: <info>  [1519184521.8409] manager: kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware' changed
Feb 20 22:45:01 Uthred kernel: [    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
Feb 20 22:45:01 Uthred kernel: [    0.144178] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
Feb 20 22:45:01 Uthred kernel: [    2.047062] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
Feb 20 22:45:01 Uthred kernel: [    8.563973] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 c3fd4411
Feb 20 22:45:01 Uthred NetworkManager[863]: <info>  [1519184701.4353] manager[0x1356200]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 20 22:45:49 Uthred ureadahead[317]: ureadahead:/home/alberto/.cache/gnome-software/3.20/firmware/firmware.xml.gz.asc: Error retrieving chunk extents: Operation not supported
```

By running `systemctl status bluetooth` I get the following:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-20 22:49:07 EST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 27733 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─27733 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Not enough free handles to register service
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Not enough free handles to register service
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb 20 22:49:07 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb 20 22:49:34 Uthred bluetoothd[27733]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_02_5B_B2_47_F1/fd0: fd(23) ready
```

Comment: What is the make and model of your bluetooth mouse?

Comment: It's a no-brand mouse (https://www.ebay.com/itm/122781287068?ViewItem=&item=122781287068). I think the culprit is not the mouse itself, since it works on my other ubuntu computer.

Comment: Did you pair the mouse to Ubuntu? You might push the button or flip that rocker switch on the bottom of the mouse first.

Comment: My laptop does not even see the mouse, so I can't pair it. I do know how to pair the mouse in general.

Answer (score 1):

## Bluetooth devices need to be paired

Before a bluetooth device can be used it needs to be paired to your Atheros WiFi card. [These instructions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-bluetooth-in-linux/) give detailed steps.

You will also need to turn over your [$8.16 bluetooth mouse](https://www.ebay.com/itm/122781287068?ViewItem=&item=122781287068) from China. There are what appears to be a rocker switch and a push button. Use one of these (the web page doesn't say which one) to activate the pairing function.

Also make sure `tlp` isn't turning off bluetooth to save power: [Connecting Bluetooth mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853507/connecting-bluetooth-mouse)

The [official / technical instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html) are here but not as easy to use as the first link I provided.

Many users find bluetooth setup frustrating and time-consuming. The best method for wireless mice and keyboards (IMO) is to use IR technology from Logitech, Microsoft and other name brand manufacturers.

Comment: I do know how to pair devices. Again, I did it successfully on another computer running ubuntu. Furthermore, my laptop has bluetooth enabled. In particular, my bluetooth headphones are working fine.

Comment: Different devices can have different methods of pairing. You need to review the instructions in the link and read the manual (or fold-out sheet) that came with your bluetooth mouse.

Comment: I paired successfully the exact same mouse already on another computer running the same OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bluetooth mouse, keyboard, or headphones you will need to look at the devices operation manual to find out how to put it in discoverable or pairing mode.

If you have another computer, tablet or smartphone, either the Ubuntu computer or the other device needs to be visible(discoverable) and then you can find it while scanning for devices.

Making your Ubuntu machine visible and scan can also be done in terminal.

Code:

```
bluetoothctl
```

This gives bluetooth control through terminal and will list the MAC address of the computers bluetooth device [controller] along with its bluetooth name and may list devices and their MAC addresses that have been paired with.

Code:

```
scan on
```

To enable scanning any visible/discoverable device should be found

Code:

```
discoverable on
```

Makes the computer discoverable by other devices. If you find the device you want to pair with after turning scan on then

Code:

```
pair
```

then enter the first 2 digits of the MAC address(case sensitive) and press TAB to autocomplete the MAC address entry, press enter and do the same for the

Code:

```
trust
```

command and then use connect command to finish, then use CTRL + d to quit bluetoothctl.

If your DE uses gnome-bluetooth the bluetooth manager might look like

[image]

and you can make the computer visible with the slider and use the + under the device window to scan, if a device is found click on it and it should give you pairing options

Comment: I still cannot see the mouse. I can, however, see and connect to other devices (e.g. my phone).